# Usage of "jed-", "jeglich-" and "jedwed-"

Tags: difference, pronoun

What is the difference between *jedwed-*, *jeglich-* and *jed-*? In my dictionary all three mean 'any'. And in what context are they used? Are they interchangeable?

Comment: [Indefinite pronouns and determiners: jeder, jedweder, jeglicher](http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-Indef/Pron-jeder3.html?lang=en)

Comment: Hallo! Like for example : Jedes/Jegliches/ Jedwedes Haus ist mir schön.

Comment: **Jedes** Haus ist schön. - Ohne *mir*.

Comment: Go with *jeder* when talking about countable things: "Jedes Kind", "Jeder Mensch", "Jede Idee", "Jede Frage", "Jedes Auto", "Jeder Versuch", "Jeder Schrank". But use *jegliche* when talking about uncountable things: "Jeglicher Zweifel", "Jegliche Art", "Jegliche Liebe", "Jegliche Möbel", "Jeglicher Strom", "Jegliches Geld". Forget about "jedweder" altogether.

Comment: @em1 but it's such a beautiful word... why should he forget about it??

Comment: @Em1 : Altmodisch oder? :)

Comment: Remember, remember jedweder November.

Comment: @Vogel612; Because it's dated and, frankly, unidiomatic in spoken German.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, I'll try a more general reply:

**jeder**, jede, jedes = every. This is the normal word to use.

**jeglicher**, jegliche, jegliches = any, somewhat higher register and (slightly?) dated, quite often used in the negative: *Der Sprecher enthielt sich jeglichen Kommentars. Jegliche Hilfe kam zu spät*. The "no exceptions whatsoever" aspect is highlighted. Can be safely replaced by "alle" or "jeder/-r/-s", as a rule.

**jedweder**, jedwede, jedwedes: ~ "each and every". Very stilted, might be used in contracts and such, certainly not in everyday conversation. Learners of German probably should stay clear.