# “Jegliche” vs. “sämtliche”

Tags: difference

What's the difference between the words *jegliche* und *sämtliche?*

I looked for the answer in the Duden dictionary, but all I found was that [they are a synonym for *all (nachdrücklich).*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/all)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For my feeling: *sämtliche* expresses that there is some set of things which is completely covered by some property while *jegliche* points more specifically at each thing in the set. (However, both meanings can be very similar or synonymous.)

This is supported by the link you posted where *jegliches* but not *sämtliches* is listed under "stärker vereinzelnd, die Einzelglieder einer Gesamtheit betrachtend; jeder, jedes, jegliches".

Also, *sämtlich* can stand on its own as in *das gilt sämtlich für Modelle dieses Typs* ("this is valid for all models of this type") while a similar construction is not possible with *jeglich* (at least I don't think so).

*Sämtliche Werke* means "the complete works" of some author while *jegliche Werke* is unusual and would only make sense in a context where there is a specific focus on each of the works such as in *jegliche Werke weisen diese Schwäche auf* ("each of the works show this deficit").

Furthermore, it has been [pointed out before](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8826/usage-of-jed-jeglich-and-jedwed?rq=1) that *jegliche* is often used in a negative context (which is not a rule for *sämtliche*):

> often used in the negative: Der Sprecher enthielt sich jeglichen Kommentars. Jegliche Hilfe kam zu spät. The "no exceptions whatsoever" aspect is highlighted. Can be safely replaced by "alle" or "jeder/-r/-s", as a rule.

Comment: I agree with this explanation and would add that the difference is similar to the one in English between *any* (used in the sense of *all*) and *all*, or between *any* and *some*. *Je-* occurs in many German words that (at least) allude to picking out a single example from a set, whereas *sämtliche* is related to (English *some* and) *gesamt = complete, total, whole*. As a result of these slightly different shades of meaning, when you want to stress the size of the set in question, you use *sämtliche*; when you stress it's small or even empty, you use *jegliche*.

Comment: Jeglich is elevated written style, hardly used in normal spoken language.

Comment: Thank you for these additions - I'm totally on board with all of them.

Comment: @rogermue: It's more "gehoben" than sämtlich, you mean?

Comment: @marmistrz - Ich denke schon. Wann verwende ich jeglich? Eigentlich nie in der Normalsprache.

Answer (score 3):

Here it is highly instructive to look at the origin of "jeglich" and some examples of usage:

> mittelhochdeutsch ieclich, iegelich, althochdeutsch iogilīh, zusammengerückt aus: io, eo = immer (je) und gilīh = gleich (welcher), jeder.
>   *Duden*

Hence, the original meaning is "**no matter which**", "**any**".

Please note the example Duden provides:

> frei von jeglichem neidischen Gefühl.

I would translate this as "free of any envious feeling". "Sämtlich" can not be used in this example. The same is true of the following sentence:

> «Er verschlang Bücher jeglicher Art.»

which I translate as "He devoured books of any kind".

"Sämtliche", on the other hand, is related to words like "Gesamtheit". It expresses "every". As in:

> «Auf seine telephonische Verständigung hin wären innerhalb einer einzigen Stunde sämtliche Hotels und Pensionen von Paris auf das genaueste untersucht worden...»
>   *Stefan Zweig*, **Die Welt von gestern**

We would not use "jegliche"'here.

Comment: What is called such a word formation actually over time i.e. mittelhochdeutsch _ieclich_, but today jeglich?

Answer (score 1):

Jeglich ist aus der gesprochenen Sprache verschwunden. Es kommt nur in geschriebener Sorache vor und ist gehobener Stil, entweder Amtsdeutsch oder literarisch.